# Sort a GridButtonColumn in a Telerik RadGrid control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I need to sort a GridButtonColumn in a C# asp.net project.

I've added the c# class listed in this thread

http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/filtering-and-sorting-for-gridbuttoncolumn.aspx

and I can't get it to work.  I get this

> The type or namespace name
>   'GridButtonColumn' could not be found

Is there using directive that I need to add?

The VB example uses `Imports Telerik.WebControls`.  When I add `using Telerik.WebControls;`  I get this message

> The type or namespace name
>   'WebControls' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Telerik' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)

---

EDIT:

I added the namespace and now I get this error

Unknown server tag 'telerik:GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSorting

Answer (score 1):

The GridButtonColumn exists in the namespace Telerik.Web.UI.  Try changing the Imports directive in your VB code from

```
Imports Telerik.WebControls
```

to

```
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
```

Response to Edit:

GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSorting is the class name of the custom GridButtonColumn that the above article creates.  In order to help you with this we probably need to see your code/markup for the your site.  In the above article it registers the custom button column as

```
<Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSortingNS">
```

Did you do this in your markup file?  If so change any

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSorting .. >
```

to

```
<custom:GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSorting . . >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a web application project there is no app_code folder. In this case you can just put the GridButtonColumnWithFiltering.cs file anywhere you want and register it like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="YourAssemblyName" TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="GridButtonColumnWithFilteringSortingNS" %>
```